# Which complete bipartite graphs (exhaustive) decompose into 2 isomorphic subgraph

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to find some hint regarding to this subject as I only found a 14 page paper dated to 1979 by S Quinn on Google.

I'm thinking about the cycle for a vertex and odd/even vertex sets.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

An obvious necessary condition for $K_{m,n}$ to be decomposed into two copies of a graph $G$, is that the number of edges in $K_{m,n}$ is twice the number of edges in $G$.  Hence $mn$ must be even.  Without loss of generality, assume $m$ is even.

A drawing of a decomposition of $K_{4,5}$ into two isomorphic graphs is given below.

[image: A decomposition of $K_{4,5}$ into two isomorphic graphs.]

In general, we can split the vertices in the part of size $m$ into two halves $A$ and $B$, and retain only the edges incident with $A$ in one graph, and retain only the edges incident with $B$ in the other graph.

The result is a decomposition of $K_{m,n}$ into two copies of the graph $K_{m/2,n}$ together with $m/2$ isolated vertices.